# best practice with memcache/php - multi memcache nodes

Tags: php, memcached, scalability

So I am working on a web app - that has to be built for scalability. It stores frequent MySQL querys into the cache. I have pretty much everything built and ready to go - but I am concerned on best practices on handling where to cache the data. I've talked to a few people and one of them suggested to split each key/value across all the memcache nodes.

Meaning if i store the example: 'somekey','this is the value'

it will be split across lets say 3 memcache servers.

Is that a better way? or is memcache more built on a 1 to 1 relationship?. For example.

store value on server A till it faults out - go to server B and store there.

that is my current understanding from the research I have done and past experience working with memcache.

Could someone please point me in the right direction in this and let me know which way is best or if I completely have this mixxed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use consistent hashing in php

See http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php

This way if a memcache server goes down, your keys won't be redistributed :)

In my experience memcache servers have been REALLY reliable, and are usually restarted due to OS upgrades and such.

If you don't use consistant hashing, then if a server goes out and comes back, then you may have an old piece of data cached on that server.

IE Memcache servers A, B

```
A: set key = 1234, value = 'abc', expires = 1 day
B:
after a time
A: vanishes
B: get key = 1234
   returns nothing
B: set key = 1234, value = 'def', exipres = 1 day
after more time
A: comes back!
```

get_key(1234) returns 'abc', because A is now available.!

-daniel